# How to fix my error after updating table in Laravel

Tags: laravel-6

I received an error after updating and uploading a picture in Laravel.

> InvalidArgumentException

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdggc.png)

**Controller**

```php
public function actedit(Request $Request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    $user->title = $Request->input('title');
    $user->description = $Request->input('description');
    $user->url = $Request->input('url');
    $file = $Request->file('avatar');
    if (!$file) {
        return redirect()->route('editprofile')->with('alert', 'foto harus diisi!');
    }
    $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = public_path('/img');
    $file->move($path, $file_name);
    $user->image = 'public/img/'.$file_name;
    $user->save();

    return redirect('profile/'.$id);
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::post('/edit/{id}', 'HomeController@actedit')->name('actedit');
```